# $.children("selector") vs $("selector", parent) vs "parent > child" selector

Tags: jquery, selector

I have the following table structure.

```
<table id='mytable'>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>A</td></tr>
            <tr><td>B</td></tr>
            <tr><td>C</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is just getting the direct `TR` elements from `mytable`. Obviously, there are 4 direct `TR` of `mytable`.

The following shows three statements. I expected they return same result. However they **don't**.

```
var mytable$ = $("#mytable");

var trcount1 = mytable$.children("tbody").children().length; // trcount1 = 4
var trcount2 = mytable$.children("tbody > tr").length; // trcount2 = 0
var trcount3 = $("tbody > tr", mytable$).length; // trcount3 = 7
```

Only the syntax for getting `trcount1` is what I wanted.

Why are `trcount2` and `trcount3` not 4?

Thanks

Alex

===================================

Thanks jfriend00's reply.

That's what I want.

```
$("> tbody > tr", mytable$).length; // 4
mytable$.find("> tbody > tr").length; // 4
```

I missed ">" before `tbody`.

Comment: `$('tbody > tr', mytable$)` is equivalent to `mytable$.find('tbody > tr');`

Comment: So you regret nesting tables? `:)`

Comment: thanks for showing variable naming etiquette for jQuery objects. var myobject$ = $('#myobjectid');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the browser, your DOM actually looks like this (note the automatic inclusion of the `<tbody>` tags):

```
<table id='mytable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr><td>A</td></tr>
            <tr><td>B</td></tr>
            <tr><td>C</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So, given that, here's how to explain your observations:

```
var trcount1 = mytable$.children("tbody").children().length; // trcount1 = 4
```

You're asking for direct children of the table that are `tbody` and then the children of that.  There is one direct child that is a `tbody` and there are four direct children of that `tbody` tag so you get 4.

---

```
var trcount2 = mytable$.children("tbody > tr").length; // trcount2 = 0
```

You're asking for direct children of the table (which is only the `tbody` object) that also match this selector `"tbody > tr"`.  Since we're only looking at direct children of the table, this is only the `tbody` object itself and the `tbody` object iself doesn't match `"tbody > tr"` the result is 0 as there are no direct children that match that criteria.

Remember `.children()` is direct children only.  If you want to consider all children and children of children, then you use `.find()` or just put the tag in the main selector.

---

```
var trcount3 = $("tbody > tr", mytable$).length; // trcount3 = 7
```

Here's you're asking for any `tr` tag inside of `mytable` that has a direct parent that's `tbody`.  There are seven of those since all `tr` tags in `mytable` match that criteria.

---

If you want just the `tr` tags in the first table, I would recommend:

```
$("#mytable > tbody > tr")   // will be 4
```

If you want all the `tr` tags in both tables, I would recommend:

```
$("#mytable  tr")   // will be 7
```

If you want just the `tr` tags in the second table, I would recommend:

```
$("#mytable table tr")   // will be 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Based on your reply. I changed my statements to what I want. `$("> tbody > tr", mytable$).length` abd `mytable$.find("> tbody > tr").length`. They both return 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`trcount1` gets all `tbody`s that are direct descendants of `mytable$` and then gets all direct descendants of that which are your four `tr`s.

`trcount2` looks for all `tr`s that are a direct descendant of a `tbody` in the children of `mytable$`. The children of `mytable$` is only the one `tbody`.

`trcount3` looks for all `tr`s that are a direct descendant of a `tbody` in the context of `mytable$`. The first four `tr`s are direct descendants of a `tbody` and the nested `tr`s are also direct descendants of a `tbody`.